# Protect HDD File access from Live CD

Tags: linux, raid

How can we protect our files from copying through another PC or Live CD (Physical Security)?
Is it possible to use RAID and secure our data?
My os is Linux.
Can recover Raid FS from other OS?

Comment: What operating system(s) are we talking about.  Windows and Linux do not understand the file permissions of each other.  The linux kernel will follow the file permissions of another linux system of course.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try Encrypted partitions/file-systems,
e.g. there is a link to Ubuntu documentation
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystemHowto

Comment: Perhaps you should explain *why* in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to security, the assumption is if someone has physical access to your computer, then they have full access to the data.

RAID does add a layer of complexity, but it is not a security measure in any way.  It offers protection from drive failure, not from data theft.

Encryption is the best way to go.  There are plenty of tools built into various Linux OS's as well as 3rd party [disk encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_disk_encryption_software) tools.  Even if someone were to steal your drives and mount them in another machine, they would have to bypass the encryption software.

Answer (score 0):

Whey you have to assume that an attacker has physical access to your hardware there is not much you can do. Lets discuss some possibilities:

- **RAID:** Using a hardware-RAID will probably be transparent to the LiveCD the attacker uses. Software-RAID just adds a little more complexity. The attacker needs to guess your RAID configuration, but this is quite easy. --> **no added security**
- **Encryption:**

  - **Hardware-encrypted drive:** the attacker can not copy your (encrypted) data without the correct password (or without disassembling the drive). --> **some security added** (We will see later why this is still insecure.)
  - **Software-encrypted drive:** the attacker could copy your (encrypted) data and try to guess/break your password in the comfort of his home. Or he could store it and hope that at some time in the future your encryption scheme will be broken. --> **some security added**
  - **Remaining problem:** there is still a thing the attacker could do since he has physical access to your machine. He could (physically) install something to get your password. For instance: a hardware key-logger or another drive that your machine will boot from. It would imitate the password login screen where you usually enter your password.

**Conclusion:** physical access means your data is not secure.

Answer (score 0):

for this I use `encfs` it works in mac, linux and possibly also windows (if anyone cares), you can make a drive that can only be seen with a passphrase, the good thing is that if you need to see it yourself with a live CD you can, provided you remember the passphrase. can also be combined with dropbox (what I do), so you have a backup, and can share encryped files among hosts.

more info in the [man pages](http://linux.die.net/man/1/encfs)